# Change size of checkbox in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox, size

In Flex, is there an easy way to change the size of a Checkbox? I want to make the checkbox bigger, but the label beside it the same font size. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I've used scaleX and scaleY.  I think the syntax is scaleX="1.5" scaleY="1.5" to make it 50% larger.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you could programatically skin the checkbox but ive never done it. Just increase the w and h passed in from the updateDisplayList(w:Number, h:Number) function when creating a programmatic skin.

Another option, albiet rather hacky, would be to make a custom control. A canvas, a label for the checkbox text and an image for the actual "check". Click on the image, if its checked it shows your unchecked image and vice versa.